# How can I trace the query produced by the documentdb Linq provider?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

How can I see the document DB sql query (in a string) generated by a linq statement before it gets sent to the server?

```
_documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<MyType>(
                        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName,
                            CollectionName)).Where(....).SelectMany(...)
```

I want to use this for tracing purposes.

Comment: The following link shows you how to do so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025712/extract-sql-query-from-linq-expressions

Comment: My question is about azure documentdb, do you recon anything on the link you posted is related?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call ToString() on the DocumentDB query to get the SQL translation of the LINQ expression that's sent over the wire.

```
string sql = client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyType>(collectionUri).Where(t => t.Name = "x").ToString();
// sql is somthing like SELECT * FROM c WHERE c["Name"] = "x"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you use `Count()` I have found.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use Fiddler and view the JSON of the request after it is sent.

View an example here:

[CosmosDB\DocumentDB Generated SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVXnk.png)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is kind of weird : It means that you have to log each and every piece of Linq code you made.

(Using AspNetCore DI).
Knowing that the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient` contains an `HttpClient`, the first thing we can do is search if we can pass our own `HttpClient`.

And we can. For example, via `CosmosClientBuilder` and using the injected `IHttpClientFactory` :

```cs
.WithHttpClientFactory(() => httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Client"))
```

If your log filters are well configured, you'll see the Request / Response in the console.

Now, we could either add a `DelegatingHandler` to our `HttpClient` this way in `ConfigureServices` or `builder.Services` in .NET 6 :

```cs
services.AddTransient<NoSqlLoggingDelegatingHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("Client")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<NoSqlLoggingDelegatingHandler>();
```

or find out if `CosmosClient` has the option to add our own, and of course it does (Example via `CosmosClientBuilder`).

```cs
.AddCustomHandlers(
    new NoSqlLoggingDelegatingHandler(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<NoSqlLoggingDelegatingHandler>()))
```

With this, we can intercept the Request and Response sent :

```cs
public override async Task<ResponseMessage> SendAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Requesting {uri}.\n{query}",
            request.RequestUri, await GetQueryAsync(request.Content));

    ResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    _logger.LogInformation("Requested {uri} - {status}",
    response.RequestMessage.RequestUri, response.StatusCode);

    return response;
}
```

And `GetQueryAsync` reads the Request's body Stream using `System.Text.Json` :

```cs
private static async ValueTask<string?> GetQueryAsync(Stream content)
{
    string? stringContents;

    // Create a StreamReader with leaveOpen = true so it doesn't close the Stream when disposed
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(content, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        stringContents = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    content.Position = 0;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringContents))
    {
        return null;
    }

    try
    {
        using JsonDocument parsedJObject = JsonDocument.Parse(stringContents);

        return parsedJObject.RootElement.GetProperty("query").GetString();
    }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException)
    {
        return stringContents;
    }
    // Not a JSON.
    catch (JsonException)
    {
        return stringContents;
    }
}
```

And there you have it. I've tried to shortened the code, for example, I didn't add a condition to check if the logging level is enabled or not, to avoid doing useless work.